# correct quotes using in sql statements

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

Sorry guys, I lost in quotes!

I have the procedure

```
# A function that takes in a PostgreSQL query and outputs a pandas database 
def create_pandas_table(sql_query, database = conn):
    table = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, database)
    return table
```

and i am trying to pass sql statement (PostgreSQL), what works fine in SQL terminal:

```
 SELECT * FROM public.payments WHERE payments."createdAt" > '2021-01-01'
```

The only way how i was able to pass correct string is:

```
date_string = "'2021-01-01'"
table_payments = create_pandas_table(r'SELECT * FROM public.payments WHERE payments."createdAt" > '+date_string)
```

I tried triple quotes, back slash ... nothing helped me.

```
r'SELECT * FROM public.payments WHERE payments."createdAt" > '''2021-01-01'''''
```

how can i pass the string in one statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
date_string = "'2021-01-01'"
table_payments = create_pandas_table(r'SELECT * FROM public.payments WHERE payments."createdAt" > {}'.format(date_string))
```

Try this one. I didn't manage to reproduce your issue, but this is an alternative way of doing concatenation.

Comment: thanks! yes, it works also. the idea not to use any additional variables like date_string and write whole statement in one line.

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.read_sql_query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) also accepts parameters, to avoid SQL injection:

> paramslist, tuple or dict, optional, default: None List of parameters
> to pass to execute method. The syntax used to pass parameters is
> database driver dependent. Check your database driver documentation
> for which of the five syntax styles, described in PEP 249’s
> paramstyle, is supported. Eg. for psycopg2, uses %(name)s so use
> params={‘name’ : ‘value’}.

Comment: Thank you. I am not going to pass parameters to the string. it is the question how to correct set the string which contains quotes marks.

Comment: You don't? But your code is actually doing it and the problems you face with quotes could be fixed by using the paramslist.

Comment: params is a workaround. I think, i simply don't know how to use ''' or \''' or chr() ... to set correct string as one line parameter. If pandas doesn't support that - it is ok, I will stay with params workaround.

Answer (score 0):

FROM https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html :

*paramslist, tuple or dict, optional, default: None
List of parameters to pass to execute method. The syntax used to pass parameters is database driver dependent. Check your database driver documentation for which of the five syntax styles, described in PEP 249’s paramstyle, is supported. Eg. for psycopg2, uses %(name)s so use params={‘name’ : ‘value’}.*

try passing parameters this way